# Sagemath available in jupyter in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am playing around with the jupyter extension inside of vscode.  And although I can use sagemath in jupyter lab on my machine it is not presented as an option of cell type within vscode.  Suggestions?

Thanks,
R Haynes